# Как выделить пояснение?

Tags: пунктуация

"Выделяют два типа басти-крийи: сухой тип, СУКШМА-БАСТИ, и водный тип, ДЖАЛА-БАСТИ". Возможно ли такое выделение: "Выделяют два типа басти-крийи: сухой тип — сукшма-басти, и водный тип — джала-басти"?

Answer (score 1):

Выделяют два типа басти-крийи: сухой тип — сукшма-басти и водный тип — джала-басти.

Думаю, что названия являются приложениями, обособленными с помощью тире. Эти приложения относятся к однородным членам, которые связаны союзом "и", поэтому запятая не ставится.

Comment: Разумно! Благодарю!